# Multiple Table View ios app

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am developing an iPhone app with several TableViews. It is similar to the SimpleDrillDown app provided on the apple developer site.

I was earlier using storyboards for this, but now have decided to go with the old approach, as  Storyboards are supported only for iOs v 5.0 and above :(

Can somebody tell me how I should proceed with such an app? It would be great if somebody could point me to an existing app with similar logic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an example but, basically, you want to take each scene in your storyboard and create a unique .xib file for its view controller.  Then you replace each segue with a call to init the controller using the matching nib and either push or present the new controller depending on whether it's a transition within a navigation controller or a modal one.